# LinkedIn V2 Public API Endpoints

Tags: linkedin-api

Can anybody help me to find out LinkedIn V2 Version public API Endpoints with respect to the scope what are the scope for it.

Which are the correct URL's to do OAuth 2.0 Authentication Process .
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

OR

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken

Answer (score 1):

For authorization :

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

For access token :

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken